# It's not obvious how to reply to a comment on a pending proposed change of mine

Tags: feature-request, bug, documentation

Yesterday I [proposed this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/85579?draftId=71821#commentId=15562), which someone then commented on.

In the process of trying to address their comment, I inadvertently managed to retract my own proposal, but I could have sworn there was no "add a comment" link to allow me to reply to the reviewer's comment.

When I look at anyone else's proposed change, or another of my proposed changes, I *do* see an "add a comment" link.

This morning, after clicking on the inbox message, the only link I ever noticed was the "retract and edit" link. I didn't see any "add a comment" link.

> > You proposed this change ...
> >
> > [retract and edit]
>
> Can you please fix UIFontWeightBold, too? FelixSFD 7 hours ago

If the "add a comment" link is actually present, could it be moved to a more prominent place (such as right below the existing reviewers' comments)? It would certainly make more sense for the person who proposed the change (since I'd be wanting to reply to their comment, rather than adding a comment to my own proposal).

I haven't been able to reproduce this today, simply because no one has **replied** to my (re)proposed change, so I can't see exactly what I would have seen yesterday.

*In the meantime, I've gone back and [preemptively commented on the second proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/85860?draftId=71821), as I hadn't thought to include that additional note to reviewers within the change notes.*